# API Endpoint Query Parameter - What is returned?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

I am looking to understand how the query parameter in RESTful APi's work with a bit more certainty. I have the following API Endpoint.

```
/objects/users
```

This would produce a list of Users as per the Controller Route and subsequent data fetched. Now what would happen if I then apply a query parameter to this? For example.

```
/objects/users?has_country=Ireland
```

Would this still query the ENTIRE User dataset, and then filter out just the people who are based in Ireland once I had already received it,  or is the query in someway applied before the dataset is returned to me?, meaning I only receive the Users from Ireland back and nothing else?

The reason I ask is that I also have an endpoint which I use to query specific countries, and just wondering if this is erroneous given I can pass a query parameter to the first Endpoint. But if there is a data overhead in terms of receiving erroneous records back, then i will keep them separate.

This country specific endpoint is

```
/objects/users/{country}
```

Comment: This is an implementation detail but there's no information about the implementation in question.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful/REST (Representational state transfer) is arhitectural pattern do not mix with some concrete implemented API.